# Need to Replace Sheet Name

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way (with code perhaps) to search and replace sheet names?

For example, I have 20 sheet names with "Direct (1)","Direct (2)" ,"Direct (3)"  and so on in the name, and
 I'ld like to replace teh "Direct (2)" in the sheet name to "Net" in
 each instance.

so it will be "Net (1)" , "Net (2)" , "Net (1)"

```
Public Sub Direct2ToNet()
     Const sRepl As String = "Direct (2)"
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim nPos

     On Error Resume Next

     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         With ws
             If .Name Like "*" & sRepl & "*" Then _
                .Name = Replace(.Name, sRepl, "Net")
         End With
     Next ws

     On Error GoTo 0
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be enough:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Direct2ToNet()
    Const sRepl As String = "Direct"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Name = Replace$(ws.Name, sRepl, "Net")
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Pᴇʜ - what does `Replace$` do as opposed to `Replace`?

Comment: @SJR `Replace$()` returns a `String` while `Replace()` returns a `Variant`. Therefore the `Replace$()` should be faster. You only need to use `Replace()` if it could happen that it needs to return `NULL`. This cannot happen here because a sheet name is never `NULL`. Therefore I chose the faster option with `String`.